# How to use php imap_sort to sort and retrieve last 10 messages

Tags: php, imap

I want to retrieve the last 10 messages from gmail account and display them in a page. I have the following so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="mail.css"/> -->

</head>

<body>
<?php

ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);
/* connect to gmail */
$user = '*****';
$password = '*********';
$mailbox = "{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX";

?>

<?php
$mbx = imap_open($mailbox , $user , $password);

/*imap_check returns information about the mailbox
including mailbox name and number of messages*/
//$check = imap_check($mbx);


/* grab emails */
$emails = imap_search($mbx, 'SINCE "10 Mar 2015"');

/* if emails are returned, cycle through each... */
if($emails) {

    /* begin output var */
    $output = '';


?>

<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">

 <tr> 
        <th>From</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Subject</th>
 </tr>

<?php    




    /* for every email... */
    foreach($emails as $email_number) {
       /* get information specific to this email */
        $overviews = imap_fetch_overview($mbx,$email_number,0);


/*imap_fetch_overview returns an overview for a message.
An overview contains information such as message subject,
sender, date, and if it has been seen. Note that it does
not contain the body of the message. Setting the second
parameter to "1:n" will cause it to return a sequence of messages*/

//$overviews = imap_fetch_overview($mbx,"1:{$check->Nmsgs}");
?>





<?php
 /* put the newest emails on top.Doesnt work.*/
 //   rsort($overviews);
 rsort($overviews);
 print_r($overviews);
foreach($overviews as $overview)
{
?>



     <tr>
          <td><?php echo $overview->from; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $overview->date; ?></td>
          <td><a href="open.php?id=<?php echo $overview->uid; ?>"><?php echo $overview->subject; ?></a></td>
     </tr>
     <?php

   }
 }     

}
?>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

I see a post here [How can I sort arrays and data in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364127/reference-all-basic-ways-to-sort-arrays-and-data-in-php/17364128#17364128) but I'm having a hard time understanding how to sort on $overviews[date]. The rsort or any other sort not working. How do you specify you want to sort on the [date] property.thanks.

P.S. here is array:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [subject] => Fwd: A Short Course  STI #4653 [from] => Fran ***8olo [to] => Fran ****lo [date] => Tue, 10 Mar 2015 12:42:46 GMT [message_id] => <-7376330247335926430@unknownmsgid> [size] => 28928 [uid] => 1532 [msgno] => 743 [recent] => 0 [flagged] => 0 [answered] => 0 [deleted] => 0 [seen] => 0 [draft] => 0 [udate] => 1425991366 ) )
```

Updated code using usort:

```
<?php

/* grab emails */
$emails = imap_search($mbx, 'SINCE "10 Mar 2015"');

/* if emails are returned, cycle through each... */
if($emails) {

    /* begin output var */
    $output = '';


?>

<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">

 <tr> 
        <th>From</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Subject</th>
 </tr>

<?php    




    /* for every email... */
    foreach($emails as $email_number) {
       /* get information specific to this email */
        $overviews = imap_fetch_overview($mbx,$email_number,0);


/*imap_fetch_overview returns an overview for a message.
An overview contains information such as message subject,
sender, date, and if it has been seen. Note that it does
not contain the body of the message. Setting the second
parameter to "1:n" will cause it to return a sequence of messages*/

//$overviews = imap_fetch_overview($mbx,"1:{$check->Nmsgs}");
?>





<?php
 /* put the newest emails on top.Doesnt work.*/
 //   rsort($overviews);
 usort($overviews, function($a1, $a2) {
   $v1 = strtotime($a1['date']);
   $v2 = strtotime($a2['date']);
   return $v1 - $v2; // $v2 - $v1 to reverse direction
});

 print_r($overviews);
foreach($overviews as $overview)
{
?>



     <tr>
          <td><?php echo $overview->from; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $overview->date; ?></td>
          <td><a href="open.php?id=<?php echo $overview->uid; ?>"><?php echo $overview->subject; ?></a></td>
     </tr>
     <?php

   }
 }     

}
?>
</table>
```

Still getting a random sort when I retrieve the emails.

Comment: You do not need to use IMAP sort.  You just need to know how many messages are in the folder, and just fetch the 10 highest ids.

Comment: Sorry stupid question how would one go about doing that? I've researched online and cant seem to find an example that shows the way you describe.

Comment: Also here is output from print_r($sorted). The msgnos are not in date order. Array ( [0] => 751 [1] => 793 [2] => 765 [3] => 855 [4] => 788 [5] => 757 [6] => 796

Comment: why is this question marked down?

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying to give as much info as possible and reading the documentation but nothing seems to work. See updated code still not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use USORT in php

```
usort($overviews, function($a1, $a2) {
   $v1 = strtotime($a1['date']);
   $v2 = strtotime($a2['date']);
   return $v1 - $v2; // $v2 - $v1 to reverse direction
});
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I still not getting any sort on the retrieved emails. I posted above how I used it. I don't know if that is what you intended.

Comment: I tried it on my non-work gmail account and it did work. Thanks. One thing though reversing $v2- $v1 is not sorting descending as I want. Any ideas on why that's the case?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it, simply use the Php built in rsort() function.

```
<?php rsort($emails); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do an array sort using `array_reverse`

```
    <?php
    $imap = imap_open(...);
    $MC = imap_check($imap);
    $overview = imap_fetch_overview($imap,"1:{$MC->Nmsgs}",0);
    $overview = array_reverse($overview);
    ?>
```